# Change the date format of a field in a trigger function in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a trigger function feeding data into a RabbitMQ exchange and all is running nicely, except for the fact that the date format isn't what the other end of the equation accepts.

There are two date fields in the database and the dates are coming out of the query as "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss" and the client wants "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" instead. (without the 'T').

The function is something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.notify_site()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql

    AS $function$
        declare
          my_record record;
        begin
          select NEW.id as id, NEW.some_date as some_date INTO my_record;
          perform pg_notify('pp_site', row_to_json(my_record)::text);
          return NEW;
        end;
    $function$
    ;
```

But I'm not sure how I can handle the time formatting in this.

To add complexity to this, I've just discovered that it might be the 'row_to_json' that is adding the 'T' as a select some_date from table1 returns the date in the correct format into pgAdmin query editor and the field type is timestamp without timezone.

Comment: `timestamp`s have no format. But you can format their *representation* when querying them e.g. with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sticky bit, I managed to get it working with

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.notify_site()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql

```
AS $function$
    declare
      my_record record;
    begin
      select NEW.id, to_char(NEW.some_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') as some_date INTO my_record;
      perform pg_notify('pp_site', row_to_json(my_record)::text);
      return NEW;
    end;
$function$
;
```